Set a question paper
I would like to know if this statement is acceptable as standard English.
I would like to set a question paper for the examination next month.

The hits that come up in the News on the Web Corpus are all for Indian English sources, suggesting that it is standard in this dialect in English, but not in others - no hits are forthcoming in the Corpus of Contemporary American English even for just 'question paper'.

But a new approach is to be adopted and faculty has to work smart to
set a question paper on this pattern. (Greater Kashmir)
Spiteful words rise up in my throat when I am interrupted – often
inadvertently – during an important work call only to help my mother
set a question paper for an exam to happen a week later. (LiveWire)
They were accused of participating in or abetting the gruesome act of
cutting off the hand of the Malayalam language teacher because he had
set a question paper in an examination in which a particular question had offended the religious sentiments of Muslims. (Deccan
Chronicle)
Since it's already brought into force, the state should now ask the
ministry of human resource development to set a question paper that
would be comfortable for our students too. (Quote in Times of
India)

There are a few British English hits for 'question paper' in the Hansard Corpus, but these seem to have the meaning of 'survey' or 'poll' rather than 'examination'.

There is very little further to say: We are very grateful to my noble
friend Lord Montgomery for reminding the Government yet again that it
is the wish of your Lordships' House--; at least it was its wish last
January--; that this whole matter should be discussed: It has gone on
for a long time: A question paper was sent out and we have the
view of many organisations: It is time that Parliament is invited to
give a view: (House of Lords, 1995)
I am sorry that the hon: Member for St: Pancras, North (Mr: Stallard) is not present, because he made some helpful suggestions whereby it would be possible to modify the question paper so that people could vote " Yes " to both questions: He might have gone further and made it even easier by suggesting that the two " Yes's " (House of Commons, 1972)

So, it depends on your audience.

I get it. Thank you

I can't see many having a knee-jerk reaction to say 'To whom do I apply to investigate the possibility of setting a question paper for the examination next month?' (on the grounds of English), but '[an] examination paper' is far more idiomatic in the UK at least. It might be difficult to avoid the second occurrence of 'examination' here, though.
